# What is the difference between Date.current and Date.today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

They both seem to do the same thing. I'm just worried that one uses timezones differently to the other.

Comment: Do you mean Date.today?  I don't think there is a Date.now.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

See Rails code, line 40 [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb).

```
# Returns Time.zone.today when <tt>Time.zone</tt> or <tt>config.time_zone</tt> are     set, otherwise just returns Date.today.
  def current
    ::Time.zone ? ::Time.zone.today : ::Date.today
  end
```

So If you defined a timezone, you'll get a zoned Date otherwise you'll get `Date.today`.

BTW there is no `Date.now`

Answer (score 30):

If you're doing comparisons you should always use `Date.current`

This is because if you're in a timezone that could be in a different day than UTC, and your timezone isn't set then you can have the situation where `Date.today == Date.tomorrow`