# Ruby date today? - unexpected behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I'm new to Ruby and am trying to figure out why the following doesn't work as expected:

```
2.2.1 :010 > user_date = Date.today
 => Sun, 31 May 2015 
2.2.1 :011 > user_date.today?
 => false
```

I'm using the Rails console and the commands are executed one after the other (with maybe a second between executions). I'm sure there is nuance that I'm not understanding, but shouldn't the second command return true instead of false? If not, why?
Thanks in advance!

Edit #1 - Additional information requested by Arup

```
 2.2.1 :013 > puts user_date.method(:today?).owner
DateAndTime::Calculations
 => nil
```

Edit #2 - So I had a hunch. I'm on US Eastern time and it was coming up to midnight when I ran into the original issue. I waited for the turn of midnight, and now the following works.

```
2.2.1 :004 > user_date = Date.today
 => Mon, 01 Jun 2015 
2.2.1 :005 > user_date.today?
 => true
```

Comment: Just to debug `puts user_date.method(:today?).owner` .... tell me the output

Comment: I just tested it on a Rails console and it worked just fine. It returned True. Ruby 2.0.0 Rails 4.0.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Date.today` belongs to core Ruby while `today?` belongs to Rails.

[Under the hood](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-today-3F), `today?` calls `Date.current`(Rails as well) instead of `Date.today`.

[Going a bit further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635363/what-is-the-difference-between-date-current-and-date-today), we find that `Date.current` takes the current Rails time zone into account if one is configured. That should be the source of your mismatch.