# Date.today not querying records in USA, but in India it does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I have some active record queries in my rails app which does some date comparisons. Queries which have Date.today does not produce results in USA, but it does produce results in India.

For example,

```
Vehicle.where('added_date >= ?', Date.today)
```

The above active record query produces results containing all the vehicles which have been added today by the user, but in USA it only produces those results with date greater than today's date.
I googled around and have changed above query to,

```
Vehicle.where('added_date >= ?', Date.current)
```

Don't know whether it will make any difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Date.current and Date.today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635363/what-is-the-difference-between-date-current-and-date-today)

Answer (score 0):

`Date.today` returns the date depending on the system time

So if you are in India and current datetime is `2018-01-10 07:04:32 +0530`

Then `Date.today` will return `2018-01-10`.

Also at the same time datetime in US will be `Tue, 09 Jan 2018 17:36:00 PST -08:00`

So for a machine in US, `Date.today` will return `09 Jan 2018`

Therefore we should try to use `Date.current` for DB query

`Date.current` returns todays date in timezone specified by your rails app

Rails Implementation for `current` method is given below([see rails code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb#L48))

```
def current
  ::Time.zone ? ::Time.zone.today : ::Date.today
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Time.now.utc you will get every where same time.