# How to make a Job time safe? Ensuring it is run when it's supposed to using Date methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, jobs, sidekiq

We have `CreditCard` related rake tasks that are supposed to be run on the 1st every month, to remind our clients to update their payment method if it expired at some point during the previous month.

```
class SomeJob < ApplicationJob

  def perform
    ::CreditCard.
      .where(expiration_date: Date.yesterday.all_month)
      .find_each do |credit_card|

      Email::CreditCard::SendExpiredReminderJob.perform_later(credit_card.id)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm concerned that this particular Job as we currently have it might not be *Time zone safe* due to the `Date.yesterday.all_month` we use to get last month's date range (remember the rake task is run on the 1st every month).

For example, if for some reason the Job were to be run past midnight (on the 2nd), it would incorrectly notify clients with cards expiring this month when it should of notified last month's expired cards.

The safest bet would be to substract more than 1 day from `Date`, but I'm not sure that's the cleanest way to go (and later on someone would not understand why we are substracting 5, 7 days or whatever).

Are there safer ways to do it?

Comment: Do you want to send these reminder emails only once? What about those cards that expired two months ago but have not been updated yet?

Comment: These reminders are supposed to start working once the feature is deployed. Previously expired cards were notified manually.

Comment: _"if it expired at some point during the previous month"_ – since credit cards are valid for whole months (e.g. `07/21`), that "some point" will be the last day of that month (e.g. 2021-07-31).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.current.prev_month.all_month`

`.current` may be better than `.today` because it checks if it is set time zone, see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635363/what-is-the-difference-between-date-current-and-date-today/19016136).

`.prev_month` or `.months_ago(1)` see https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Date/prev_month